# best approach for choosing preprocessor defines with TeamCity?

Tags: c#, deployment, teamcity

I would like the ability to select which "conditional compilation symbols" are used with my TeamCity build. We have a few that enable customer-specific features. Do most people just have separate builds configured -- one for each possible combination? Or is there some way in TeamCity to set up a little checkbox list of these critters? I see how to do it with their parameter dialog, but that seems prone to error and not well suited for an arbitrary number of these conditional items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run builds with different settings only occasionally and just want to have some predefined values for a single parameter, then you can define the set for using [typed parameters](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Typed+Parameters).

There is no way (yet) to share that definition easily between different TeamCity build configurations apart from defining the parameter on project level or in a build configuration template.

Comment: Thanks. The trick to seeing the "Checkbox" option is behind that little edit button at the bottom of the custom parameter dialog.